# I tried the below code with Node.js but showing syntax error

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Showing Error syntax error at or near ","

app.post("/registred/insert",(req, res)=>{

```
const empid =  req.body.input.empid;
const empname = req.body.input.empname;
const username = req.body.input.username; 
const emppwd =  req.body.input.emppwd;
const empstatus = "Pending";

const pginsert = "INSERT INTO users (emp_id, emp_name, user_name, password, emp_status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";        

client.query(pginsert, [empid, empname, username, emppwd, empstatus], (err, result)=>{            

    if(!err){      
        console.log(result);
    }else {
        console.log(err.message);
    } 
    client.end;
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Mmh is equal to this?

```
app.post("/registred/insert", (req, res) => {
  const empid = req.body.input.empid;
  const empname = req.body.input.empname;
  const username = req.body.input.username;
  const emppwd = req.body.input.emppwd;
  const empstatus = "Pending";

  const pginsert =
    "INSERT INTO users (emp_id, emp_name, user_name, password, emp_status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
  client.query(
    pginsert,
    [empid, empname, username, emppwd, empstatus],
    (err, result) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(result);
      } else {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
      client.end;
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: yes, but shwoing syntax Error  = > syntax error at or near ","